# Interchanging from a function defined by an integral to indefinite integral

Tags: definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

This question might be trivial, but I have the following:

$$\operatorname{E}_n(x) = \int_{0}^{x} e^{-t^2}t^n \, dt$$

If I have $\operatorname{E}_n(x)$ as a function defined as an integral, it is correct to say

$$\operatorname{E}_n = \int e^{-x^2}x^n \, dx ?$$

Answer (score 0):

$\int e^{-x^2}x^n \, dx$ denotes the set of all antiderivatives of $e^{-x^2}x^n$.

$E_n(x) = \int_{0}^{x} e^{-t^2}t^n \, dt$ is a special antiderivative of $e^{-x^2}x^n$ because of $E_n(0)=0.$

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on why $E_n(0) = 0$ implies $E_n(x)$ is a special antiderivative of $e^{-x^2}x^n$?

Comment: The set of all antiderivatives of $e^{-x^2}x^n$ is given by $\{E_n+C: C \in \mathbb R\}.$ You get $E_n$ with $C=0.$

Answer (score 0):

As the name indicates, an indefinite integral is not completely defined, it represents a family of functions. So, no it is not really correct.

To some extent one might admit the equivalence

$$\int f(t)\,dt=\int_a^x f(t) dt$$ where $a$ is unspecified.

Comment: I'm sure I've seen the notation $\int f(t)\,dt=\int^x f(t)\,dt$, but I don't recall where.

Comment: @saulspatz: makes sense. I wrote "to some extent" because by application of the FTC, we get $F(x)-F(a)$ (resp. $F(x)-F(\ )$ :-) ), and it is not always true that $-F(a)$ can match any constant.

Comment: Is there any way I can express $\int e^{-x^2}x^n \, dx$ in terms of $E_n(x)$?

Comment: @abrakadabra_01: obviously, $E_n(x)+C$.

Comment: Is that because $E_n(x)$ is a "one" of the many antiderivatives of $\int e^{-x^2}x^n \, dx$?

Comment: @abrakadabra_01: yes. If you prefer, because $(E_n(x)+C)'=e^{-x^2}x^n$.